# Substracting water mask

Tags: raster, polygon, vector, water

I have a polygon with water bodies of my AOI. I would like to clip the water bodies from my NDVI raster layer ( like a water mask). I haven't found a tool in qgis or arcgis pro so far.

Do you have any tips for me? As a result I want to have my ndvi layer without the water bodies.

Comment: Are you asking to have the pixels under your water body polygons to be set to NODATA? Also choose ONE GIS system. Update your question.